# Include NULL as 0 in COUNT SQL Query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, ajax

I know for a fact this has been asked a few times before, but none of the answered questions relating to this seem to work or are far too confusing for me..

I should probably explain.

I'm trying to create an AJAX script to run to order some results by the number of 'Likes' it has.

**My current code is this:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, likes.palette_id, palette.*
FROM likes LEFT JOIN palette ON likes.palette_id = palette.palette_id

GROUP BY likes.palette_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Which works fine, however it doesn't list the results with 0 likes for obvious reasons, they don't exist in the table.

**I've attached images of the current tables:**

Likes table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY6UX.jpg

Palette table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g99Cp.jpg

There are no results in the *likes* table until the user clicks 'Like'. It is then that the database gets updated and the palette_id and user_id are inserted.

**I'm trying to count how many times *palette_id* occurs in the likes table but also display 0 for all palettes that don't appear in the likes table.**

Is this possible? If so, can someone help me out at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the exact MySQL syntax (I'm used to SQL Server), but should be pretty straight forward to translate if needed.

```
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(l.total, 0) AS total
FROM palette p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT palette_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY palette_id
) l
ON l.palette_id = p.palette_id
ORDER BY total
```

Comment: I understand what you've put, but I think something may be missing? I'm getting a syntax error around the (l.total, 0)...

Comment: @DavidPottrell: do we need to guess or you provide the exact error message?

Comment: My apologies, It just looked like a typical syntax error but I may be wrong! #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 0) AS total
FROM palette p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT palette_id, COUNT(*) AS total' at line 1

Comment: @DavidPottrel: sheck plalx's answer now ([`ISNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) -> [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull))

Comment: @zerkms No worries, I'm actually glad you made it better! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(likes.palette_id) AS total, palette.palette_id, palette.*
FROM palette LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.palette_id = palette.palette_id
GROUP BY palette.palette_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

EDIT:

In regards to the discussion about listing columns that are not in the GROUP BY, there's a good explanation in this [MySql documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer
>   to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

In this example, the palette information not added to the GROUP BY will be the same for each group because we are grouping by palette_id so there won't be any issue using palette.*

Comment: Is it normal that you can select more fields that those listed in the group by statement? That's incorrect in MSSQL.

Comment: @plalx: mysql forgives you some stupid things :-) PS: though it *is* possible to set it up to respect some strict requirements

Comment: @plalx, you are right, I just focused on the join part. thanks for noticing that

Comment: @zerkms Yeah that's what I tought, because it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Esteban-Everdin: This works perfectly! So is there a smarter way of getting all results from the palette table along with the count? Thanks though!

Comment: @zerkms, it ignores the fields that are not in the group by or shows them anyway?

Comment: @EstebanElverdin That's why you normally isolate the grouping statement like in my answer. That allows you to select more columns without grouping by multiple fields.

Comment: @Esteban Elverdin: it shows "the first to arrive" row. So basically it's mostly unpredictable

Comment: @zerkms,plalx, didn't know that, interesting, thanks

Comment: Is there anything 'wrong' about using pallete.* in the select statement? Or is there simply a smarter way of doing it? (I believe @plalx suggested one alternative answer)

Comment: @DavidPottrell: no, it's fine. And actually plax also selects `palette.*`

Comment: @DavidPottrell, most rdbms doesn't allow that, it seems MySql do. In others databases you have to add all fields that you need to show in the select in the group by clause, that's all

Comment: Ah okay I understand - Thank you for all your help and explaining everything! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Your join is written backwards.  It should be palette LEFT JOIN likes, because you want all rows in palette and rows in likes, if they exist.  The "all rows in palette" will get you a palette_id for the entries there without any matching "likes."